# What is a quick algorithm to find X by Y zeros in 2d matrix?

Tags: c#, algorithm, search

I'm looking for an algorithm that can quickly find rectangles of `0`'s in a matrix with random digits 0-9 that are not smaller than X and Y in lengths.

My own just scans for 0's and looks if there is an adjacent rectangle, if not, continues. It's rather slow, so maybe there is something quicker.

Comment: Should the rectangle be "filled" with zeros ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. The rectangle must consist of zeros only.

Comment: Could you post your algo, because I don't understand your explanations.

Comment: How large a matrix are we talking about ?

Comment: If you included your code, this might also be relevant for [codereview.se]. In any case, you need to include a sample matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table with the same size as the original. Sweep original vertically and count the number of consecutive zeros above and including the current field, write this into the new table.

Sweep original table horizontally count the number of consecutive zeros left of and including the current field. Then for each field those two numbers tell you the size of the rectangle ending at that field.

The rest of the solution depends on parts of the question you didn't specify. Perhaps you can simply output them whenever they're large enough, perhaps you need to add some test to check if you're at the bottom right corner of a rectangle.

Comment: So there should be a new array of points the size of the original matrix with each point's coordinates holding the size of zero-filled field above and to the left from it (point)?

Comment: @user1306322 Yes that's one way to do it. You probably can omit the second table by directly checking the output condition during the second sweep.

Comment: It seems that your method is wrong, for example, [1 0; 0 0], your method will output a wrong answer with a 2x2 matrix, right?

Comment: @shilk I don't see the problem. That algorithm will tell you that there is a 1x1 rectangle at (1,0), which is correct.

Comment: @CodesInChaos sorry, my previous comment is incomplete, I have edited it.

Comment: You might be able to adapt the answer from stackoverflow.com/questions/2478447